# finding nearest date available in mysql database when date added is out of range

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query where mysql searches for nearest date available if date added is out of range

my query code is

```
SELECT B.ticker,B.date S_date, B.close S_close, E.date E_date, E.close E_close, ROUND(( E.close - 
B.close)/B.close * 100,2) perc FROM ( SELECT ticker, date, close FROM stocks WHERE date = 
"2020-09-15") B inner join (SELECT ticker, date, close FROM stocks WHERE date = "2022-10-13" )
 E on B.ticker = E.ticker  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

In above code I am trying to find dates to get close values

first date is 2020-09-15 and second date is 2022-10-13

I need to get exact dates to get close values to calculate perc

```
ROUND(( E.close - B.close)/B.close * 100,2) perc
```

Now, the issue is when the dates is out of range in database.

e.g.

I have data available from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31. When user puts dates similar to current sql query where dates are out of range, the mysql is giving empty query result

So, I need to modify my query so that if dates are out of range, then mysql searches for nearest date available instead of giving empty result.

if dates are out of range then 2021-01-01 should be used as b date and 2021-12-31 as e date

mysql table screenshot

[image]

please help me.

thanks

Comment: Can we please have the table structure and sample data?  People tend to be more willing to help if `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements are provided.

Comment: Please also define what you mean by the nearest date. In your testing query, the first date is "2020-09-15" and the second date is "2022-10-13", while your data available is from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31. So both the first date and the second date are out of range. Does this mean we should use 2021-01-01 as the first date and 2021-12-31 as the second date? If so, can we just say use the earlist date available for first date if out of range and the latest date available for second date if out of range ?

Comment: yes, if dates are out of range then 2021-01-01 should be used as b date and 2021-12-31 as e date

Comment: There are a total of four cases which are mutually exclusive (only one case stands true at a time)  1.both legit; 2.both out of range; 3. 1st legit 2nd out of range; 4. 1st out of range 2nd legit. Try `UNION`.